# I debugged a SDL2 Program in Visual Studio and I had to force-quit, and now my screen is brighter out of the program. Why, and how do I fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, memory-management, sdl-2

I was making a little program to practice pointer usage and rendering.
I was trying to debug an Illegal memory access, and my program crashed.

The problem, is that it crashed and I had to force-quit the debugging session by pressing shift-f5
because my program was taking mouse focus, and I could not click anything.
Now my screen is constantly brighter than before, probably due to an draw operation that was supposed to draw a fullscreen white rectangle.

This will probably be fixed when I restart my PC.... but it is still a problem if this stacks, since I will have to restart every 3 debugging sessions to not burn my eyes.

Any advice on how to ENSURE my program releases resources?
Edit for reproducible example:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_render.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H


struct element {
    SDL_Rect* area;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Surface* surface;
    std::string name = "";
    std::function<void()> functionPointer;
    element(SDL_Rect* rect, SDL_Texture* tex, SDL_Surface* surf, std::string elementName, std::function<void()> fp) {
        area = rect;
        texture = tex;
        surface = surf;
        name = elementName;
        functionPointer = fp;
    }
    ~element() {
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        area = nullptr;
        surface = nullptr;
        texture = nullptr;
        name = "";
        functionPointer = nullptr;
    }
};


struct screenVariables {
    std::list<SDL_Texture*> textureList;
    std::list<element*>& elementList;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    std::list<SDL_Surface*> surfaceList;
    screenVariables(std::list<SDL_Texture*> tex, std::list<element*> rec, SDL_Renderer* render,std::list<SDL_Surface*> surf) :
        textureList(tex),elementList(rec), renderer(render),surfaceList(surf) {};

};





class gameHandler{
private:
    SDL_Window* screen;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Texture* mainBlock;
    bool saveAvailable = false;
    bool quit = false;
    std::list<SDL_Texture*> textureList;
    std::list<element*> elementList;
    std::list<SDL_Surface*> surfaceList;
    screenVariables screenInfo{ textureList, elementList, renderer, surfaceList };

    void nothing() {};

    void continuePressed() {};

    void newGame() {};



 public:
     gameHandler() {
         SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS);
         TTF_Init();
         screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Window",
             SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
             SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
             1920, 1080,
             SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
         renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);
         mainBlock = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888,
             SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 1920, 1080);

     }

     //All methods that do operations on elements will operate on the LAST ADDED ELEMENT. Always create a new element and use push_back() to add it to the end.
//Everything commented out is not nessesary for reproduction, but 
//will be left for reference.
    /*bool showFirstElement(screenVariables& arg, const char* imgPath, SDL_Rect* area) {
        SDL_Renderer* renderRef = arg.renderer;
        //The following line means: end() returns an iterator, take the iterator and make it go back once, then deference it to get the value.
        //This gets the value of the last added surface.
        SDL_Surface* newSurface = *(--(arg.surfaceList.end()));
        newSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(imgPath);
        SDL_Texture* newTexture = *(--(arg.textureList.end()));
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderRef, newSurface);
        std::function<void()> nothingWrapper = [&]() { nothing(); };
        element* toBeModified = *(--(arg.elementList.end()));
        toBeModified->element::area = area;
        toBeModified->texture = newTexture;
        toBeModified->surface = newSurface;
        toBeModified->name = imgPath;
        toBeModified->functionPointer = nothingWrapper;
        arg.elementList.push_back(toBeModified);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderRef, newTexture, NULL, area);
        return true;

    }

    bool textOnElement(screenVariables& arg, const char* text,int points, element* el) {
        SDL_Renderer* renderRef = arg.renderer;
        TTF_Font* font = NULL;
        SDL_Color textColor = { 0,0,0 };
        font = TTF_OpenFont("TravelingTypewriter.ttf", points);
        SDL_Surface* newSurface = *(--(arg.surfaceList.end()));
        newSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,text,textColor);
        SDL_Texture* newTexture = *(--(arg.textureList.end()));
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderRef, newSurface);
        el->surface = newSurface;
        el->texture = newTexture;
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderRef, newTexture, NULL, el->area);
        return true;

    }

    element* checkClickedElement(screenVariables& arg, SDL_Point pos) {
        for (element* i : arg.elementList) {
            if (SDL_PointInRect(&pos, i->area)) {
                return i;
            }
            return nullptr;
        }

    }
    bool fillWithColor(screenVariables& arg, Uint32 red, Uint32 green, Uint32 blue, Uint32 alpha) {
        SDL_Renderer* renderRef = arg.renderer;
        SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 1920, 1080, 8, red, green, blue, alpha);
        SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderRef, surface);
        SDL_Rect fullScreen = { 1920,1080 };
        std::string name = "R" + std::to_string(red) + "G" + std::to_string(green) + "B" + std::to_string(blue);
        std::function<void()> nothingWrapper = [&]() { nothing(); };
        element newElement = element(&fullScreen, texture, surface, name, nothingWrapper);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderRef, texture, NULL, NULL);
        return true;
    }

    bool fillElementPointer(screenVariables& arg, SDL_Point leftTop, SDL_Point rightBottom, std::function<void()> fp,std::string name,element* newElement) {
        SDL_Rect newRect;
        newRect.x = (leftTop.x + rightBottom.x) / 2;
        newRect.y = (leftTop.y + rightBottom.y) / 2;
        newRect.w = (rightBottom.x - leftTop.x);
        newRect.h = (leftTop.y - rightBottom.y);
        newElement = &element(&newRect, nullptr, nullptr, name, fp);
        arg.elementList.push_back(newElement);
        return true;
    }
    //This allows me to create pointers that will not go out of scope when methods return. Always use this method if the element you will create needs to presist through functions.
    element* createElementPointer(){
        element* newPointer = nullptr;
        return newPointer;
    }

    int showMenu(screenVariables& arg) {

        fillWithColor(arg, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_Point leftTop = { 200,700 };
        SDL_Point rightBottom = { 600,200 };
        std::function<void()> nothingWrapper = [&]() { nothing(); };
        element* titleText = createElementPointer();
        if (!fillElementPointer(screenInfo, leftTop, rightBottom, nothingWrapper, "titleText", titleText)) {
            std::cout << "createElement failed in showMenu()";
        }
        leftTop.y = 100;
        rightBottom.x = 0;
        element* continueOrStart = createElementPointer();
        if (saveAvailable) {
            std::function<void()> continueWrapper = [&]() { continuePressed(); };
            if (!fillElementPointer(screenInfo, leftTop, rightBottom, continueWrapper, "continueButton", continueOrStart)) {
                std::cout << "createElement failed in showMenu() saveAvailable.";
            }
            textOnElement(arg, "Continue", 16, continueOrStart);
        }
        else {
            std::function<void()> newGameWrapper = [&]() { newGame(); };
            if (!fillElementPointer(screenInfo, leftTop, rightBottom, newGameWrapper, "newGameButton", continueOrStart)) {
                std::cout << "createElement failed in showMenu() !saveAvailable.";
            }
            textOnElement(arg, "New Game", 16, continueOrStart);
        }

        return 0;





    }



    void mainLoop() {
        SDL_Event event;
        showMenu(screenInfo);
        while (!quit) {
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
                switch (event.type)
                {
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                        SDL_Point position = { event.button.x,event.button.y };
                        element* result = checkClickedElement(screenInfo, position);
                        if (result == nullptr) {
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            result->functionPointer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }


    }
    void clearResources() {
        int index{ 0 };

        for (element* i : screenInfo.elementList) {
            delete i;
        }

        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);

        SDL_Quit();
    } */



};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gameHandler handler; //This alone makes my screen brighter.
    //Uncomment every function and let mainLoop() run, and it crashes.
    //Although many attempts at making this exception safe, it did not work.
    //handler.mainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Were you fiddling with the display/window gamma via `SDL_SetWindowBrightness()`/`SDL_SetWindowGammaRamp()`?  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I did not use neither of those functions. Also I just added the code. The code works fine but leaves your screen brighter and eats resources even after closed, and crashes if you uncomment all functions and let it run the way it was supposed to.